# Add lines in Allure test output

Tags: python

I would like to add some lines from the log of my py.test tests.

Although the only thing that I was able to find is the `attachment` statement, which does not exactly print text in the test output, but add a file with the text.

Is there a way to get some log lines printed in the test? I am using the py.test adapter for python

Comment: what is the problem? The file with test attachment will be available in the report. In some cases it is makes sense to use steps instead of attachments to add some details about your tests execution

Comment: Well, the problem is that I would like to show in the test info, some extra info; like a line or 2 at most. To check the attachment you have to click down to the point where there are too many side panel open. I think using steps is the way to go. Thanks